# Label grouped bar plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm tryng to add label to a grouped bar plot in r.
However I'm using percentege in the y axis, and I want the label to be count.
I've tried to use the geom_text() function, but I don't how exacly the parameters i need to use.

```
newdf3 %>%
  dplyr::count(key, value) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(key) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(p = n / sum(n)) %>%
  ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(
    mapping = aes(x = key, y = p, fill = value),
    stat = "identity",
    position = position_dodge()
  ) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(),limits=c(0,1))+
  labs(x = "", y = "%",title="")+ 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('Before' = "deepskyblue", 'During' = "indianred1", 'After' = "green2", '?'= "mediumorchid3"),
                    drop = FALSE, name="")
```

[image: plot1]

Here is an exemple of how I need it:

[image: plot2]

here's a sample of data I'm using:

```
key   value

A     Before
A     After
A     During
B     Before
B     Before
C     After
D     During
...
```

I also wanted to keep the bars with no value (label = 0).

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: can you try and use dput to provide your dataset, it's a bit unusual, and because of the position dodge, adding labels can be a bit tricky

Answer (score 1):

Here is [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of how to add count labels to a simple bar chart. See below for the case when these are grouped.

```
library(datasets)
library(tidyverse)

data <- chickwts %>% 
          group_by(feed) %>% 
          count %>% 
          ungroup %>% 
          mutate(p = n / sum(n))

ggplot(data, aes(x = feed, y = p, fill = feed)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  geom_text(stat = "identity",
            aes(label = n), vjust = -1)
```

[image: Bar plot with labels.]

You should be able to do the same thing on your data.

EDIT: StupidWolf points out in the comments that the original example has grouped data. Adding `position = position_dodge(0.9)` in `geom_text` deals with this.

Again, no access to the original data, but here's a different MWE using `mtcars` showing this:

```
library(datasets)
library(tidyverse)

data <- mtcars %>% 
  as_tibble %>% 
  transmute(gear = as_factor(gear), 
            carb = as_factor(carb), 
            cyl = cyl) %>% 
  group_by(gear, carb) %>% 
  count

ggplot(data, aes(x = gear, y = n, fill = carb)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", 
           position = "dodge") +
  geom_text(aes(label = n),
            stat = "identity",
            vjust = -1,
            position = position_dodge(0.9))
```

[image: Bar plot with group labels.]

Comment: the question shows a side by side barplot, so it might be a bit more trickier. I guess the dataset should be provided..

Comment: You're right, thank you for pointing that out. Please see edit which may reflect OP's use case more closely. Hard to mimic it exactly without the original data, as you say.